# How can i Integrate my custom method inside elide

Tags: spring, java-11, boot, json-api, elide

I want to create a method that ping the backend server and get me some informations, i want this methos to be integrated with the Elide endpoint for an entity called ping to get the response as JSON/API. But i always find my self restricted to the methods givin by Elide and my methos is exposed alone. So how can i add some customized methods to the Elide interface with my own logic.
am working with java 11,spring boot 2.7.13, elide 6.1.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elide 6 require using the dataStore. if you are looking for a custom results in the Elide Endpoint you can work with Computed attributes. Try also to map your Dao in the dataLoader .

Hope this helps